# Encoding string for form post in django/python

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to import CSV strings into my model in django and it keeps throwing

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's my current view code.

```
def saveLoot(request):
    if 'q' in request.POST:
        scsv = request.POST['q']
        f = StringIO.StringIO(scsv)
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            user = UserProfile.objects.get(character=row[3])
            loot = Loot(loot_id=row[0], item_name=row[1], source=row[2], winner=user, loot_type=row[4], lockout_tier=row[5], time=row[6], date=row[7])
            loot.save() 
        message = "I like pie, it's good, and guess what. I've saved that for you."
    else:
        message = 'Fill the damn box in will you.'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

It seems where I'm trying to pull user from the UserProfile model characters with accents do not encode correctly forcing this error.

I know this is something probably really basic and I've tried setting the default encoding, it's been a while since I last looked at python (nearly 12 months).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remembered how to do it now.

I'm certainly not sure if it's the most effective way of doing it but here's how I tackled it.

```
scsv = request.POST['q'].encode('utf-8')
```

If anyone has a better way of doing so, then I'd be grateful.